# Laravel: how to add where clause using query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, query-builder

I have this query, made using Laravel query builder:

```
$rows = DB::table('elements')->where('type', 1);
```

That corresponds to: "SELECT * from elements WHERE type=1"

Now, in some cases I need to add a second Where to create a query like this:

```
SELECT * from elements WHERE type=1 AND lang='EN'
```

Using classic `php` I'd do something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from elements WHERE type=1';

if($var==true) $sql .= " AND lang='EN'";
```

How can I do that using Laravel Query Builder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
$query =  DB::table('elements');
$query->where('some_field', 'some_value');

// Conditionally add another where
if($type) $query->where('type', 1);

// Conditionally add another where
if($lang) $query->where('lang', 'EN');

$rows = $query->get();
```

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256420/741747).

Comment: They could also be chained: `$query->where('some_field', 'some_value')->where('type', 1);`

Comment: @ManuelPedrera, Yes, but to add `where` conditionally, you cant chain, because `OP` is about to check a condition before (s)he adds another where clause.

Comment: @RCV Yes, that's why I posted a comment to expand, and not another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userId = Auth::id();
$data['user_list'] =DB::table('users')->
select('name')->
where('id','!=',$userId)->
where('is_admin','!=','1')->
get();
```

like that you use multiple where clause :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.